# NHibernate - using properties from set in subselect

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

I have the fallowing mapping:

```
<class name="Country" table="Country" lazy="false"  >
  <cache usage="read-write"/>
  <id name="Id" column="Id" type="Guid">        
                <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>
  <property name="Name" column="Name" type="String" length="50" not-null="true" unique="true"  />
  <set name="LocalizedProperties" where="LocalizedEntityClass = 'Prayon.Entities.Country'" cascade="delete">
    <key column="EntityId" foreign-key="none" />
    <one-to-many class="LocalizedProperty" />
  </set>
</class>
```

LocalizedProperty is declared as follows:

```
<class name="LocalizedProperty" table="LocalizedProperty">
 <cache usage="read-write"/>
  <id name="Id" column="Id">
    <generator class="guid.comb"/>
  </id>
  <property name="CultureName"  not-null="true"/>
  <property name="PropertyName"  not-null="true"/>
  <property name="PropertyValue"  not-null="true"/>

  <any id-type="Guid" name="Entity">
    <column name="LocalizedEntityClass"  not-null="true"/>
    <column name="EntityId"  not-null="false"/>
  </any>
</class>
```

Now I try to create a select with hql which should return all Countries, with the fallowing "normal" SQL-Select

```
select * 
from Country a 
where (
  select top 1 PropertyValue 
  from LocalizedProperty x 
  where x.EntityId = a.Id 
    and x.PropertyName = 'Name' 
    and x.LocalizedEntityClass = 'Prayon.Entities.Country' 
    and x.CultureName = 'de') 
  Like 'a%'
```

When I create the hql like

```
from Country a 
where (
  select PropertyValue 
  from LocalizedProperty x 
  where x.EntityId = a.Id 
    and x.PropertyName = 'Name' 
    and x.LocalizedEntityClass = 'Prayon.Entities.Country' 
    and x.CultureName = 'de' take 1) 
  Like :val
```

and set the parameter val to a%

I get the following `QueryException`:

> could not resolve property: EntityId of: Prayon.Entities.LocalizedProperty 
>    [from Country a where (select PropertyValue from LocalizedProperty x 
>     where x.EntityId = a.Id and x.PropertyName = 'Name' and x.LocalizedEntityClass = 'Prayon.Entities.Country' 
>     and x.CultureName = 'de' take 1) Like :val]

I hope someone can help me how to setup my hql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any "any"-type has two special properties "id" and "class", so you should be able to do something with them like this

```
from Country a 
where (
  select PropertyValue 
  from LocalizedProperty x 
  where x.Entity.id = a.Id 
    and x.PropertyName = 'Name' 
    and x.Entity.class = 'Prayon.Entities.Country' 
    and x.CultureName = 'de' take 1) 
  Like :val
```

Im not 100% sure the above is correct as i don't see exactly what you are doing. A discussion about whether you really need any for the kind of localization you seem to be doing would be good i think.

Nevertheless i am pretty sure .id and .class is the key to solve your immediate challenge.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
from Country a 
where (
  select PropertyValue 
  from LocalizedProperty x 
  where x.Entity = a
    and x.PropertyName = 'Name' 
    and x.CultureName = 'de' take 1) 
  Like :val
```

Comment: this gives me a TypeMismatchException with the fallowing message: left and right hand sides of a binary logic operator were incompatibile [Object : Prayon.Entities.Country] :-(